# How to use Keyboard Interface using Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I use Actions(Keyboard keyboard) or Actions(Keyboard keyboard, Mouse mouse) as shown in the screenshot? Request you to provide few examples.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try the [documentation](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html). The easiest way to use it would just be to pass whatever WebDriver you're using to drive the automation, and it can be useful for clicking, dragging, and sending keys (including key combinations).

Comment: Hi..Thanks! I am aware of doing the same with Webdriver. Just wanted to know how it is done by passing Keyboard.